Unabe to do KVM networking over WiFi Interface
Running Ubuntu Server 24.04. I am trying to connect a Debian VM (KVM) to be accessible through my Home Network. Host to VM communication is not necessary.
On the host Machin there is a Lan port that I would like to keep unchanged to keep stable access through a Static IP Address. Additionally, I have a WiFi Interface I would like to experment with. I have tried the following:
My first approach is to create a Virtual Network with WiFi Interface which has resulted in some issues. Because I am running Pi-Hole on my Ubuntu machin in a Docker container, the port 53 is in Use. To get Pi-Hole to run I had to set DNSStubListener=no in /etc/systemd/resolved.conf. It works as expected. When trying to create or start a Virtual Network, I am faced with this error:

Error creating virtual network: internal error: Child process
(VIR_BRIDGE_NAME=virbr0 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq
--conf-file=/var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/network.conf --leasefile-ro --dhcp-script=/usr/lib/libvirt/libvirt_leaseshelper) unexpected exit status 2:  dnsmasq: failed to create listening socket for
192.168.100.1: Address already in use

I can only bypass this error when adding <dns enable="no"/> to the networks XML. Only then my network cannot establish a connection and the network is stuck in "Configuring IP". Also using WiFi Interface as carier prevents me from connecting to WiFi:

 [1719477372.0065] device (wlx984827caaf49): supplicant
interface state: completed -> disconnected  [1719477371.8802]
device (wlx984827caaf49): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason
'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')  [1719477371.8790] device
(wlx984827caaf49): Activation: failed for connection 'mywifinetwork'

Second approach was to Bridge Interface. I tried to create a Bridge from terminal but once again I am unable to activate the WiFi interface and I am unable to connect. Same errors as before.
Removing saved WiFi networks and reconnecting removes the WiFi interface from the Bridge as carier.
Third  approach is to directly bind the VM to an WiFI interface. Although WiFi remain connected, the VM is disconnected and unable to see the connection.
How can I set the VM to get a Lan IP on home network, Have access to the internet and be accessble? Pointers to what is causing the Issue are a greate help!
Edit (1)
I learned that it is not posible to bridge wifi devices. Can someone confirm this?
Nevertheless it should be posible to add WiFi devices to NAT.
To eleminate the posibility that the issue is caused by the VM, I did create a VM in Virt Manager. I then installed Ubuntu from scratch. Yet, all approaches described above (Directly Binding the Interface; Virtual Network with Interface as carier; Bridge to the Interface) failed the same way.
My current Workaround is to map the WiFi directly into the VM as USB Device. Because VM has no Internet connection, I am unable to install additional tools to connect to WiFi. Not a solution to just avoid the Issue.

All the issues in this question seem to relate to the VM that is running. This is not a Ubuntu OS as you have stated.

As described, even befor starting a VM, I am unable to establish a connection through the WiFi interface, if it was added as a carier to Virtual network or Bridge.
To eleminate the posibility that the issue is caused by the VM, I did create a VM in Virt Manager. I then installed Ubuntu from scratch. Yet, all approaches described above (Directly Binding the Interface; Virtual Network with Interface as carier; Bridge to the Interface) failed the same way.

You might want to add this additional info to the question-

It seems that WiFi interface has some issues with VLAN, Bridge and direct networking. I have attemped a similar setup with a LAN Dongle and the results were positive. I did not dive deep enough to figure out what was causing the WiFi interface to have such issues but i suspect it has something to do with network authentication.
